# express/sails.js modules export private methods and other modules relation

Tags: node.js, sails.js, commonjs

I understand the purpose of module.export

Basically, it expects an object of functions:

```
// Parent.js
module.exports = {
createChild: function(req, res) { ... Child.Create(..) .. }
}
```

1) How the functions inside the module object are able to call other Modules?
For example, in Parent.js, I can also call another module Child.js.

2) What If I want to add Private function to Parent.js (aren't accessible via require) that can access Parent DB just like functions inside module.export

For instance:

```
 // Parent.js
 function validateInput(req) {
 }
 module.export = { }
```

Answer (score 2):

> I understand the purpose of module.export
>
> Basically, it expects an object of functions:

Not necessarily. You can assign anything to `module.exports`, e.g. an object, an array, a function or even just a value.

> 1) How the functions inside the module object
>   are able to call other Modules? For example, in Parent.js, I can also
>   call another module Child.js.

In this case your parent module has to `require` your child module, e.g.:

```
// Parent.js
module.exports = {
  createChild: function(req, res) {
    ...
    var Child = require('./child');
    Child.Create(..) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

> 2) What If I want to add Private function to Parent.js (aren't
>   accessible via require) that can access Parent DB just like functions
>   inside module.export.

Whatever is not accessible via `module.exports` is not (directly) accessible from the outside. For example, in your case you won't be able to call `validateInput` directly from another module.

Please read the [official documentation on modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) and / or [CommonJS specs](http://www.commonjs.org/), it really helps.

Comment: I didn't add require explicitly. does NodeJS do anything behind the scenes with module.exports? if I have Parent.js and Child.js, in SailsJS, I don't add any require statement to any of them. I can call Parent.Create(...) from Child.js (inside module.export) without any problem.

Comment: If `Parent.js` and `Child.js` are Sails.js models, then yes, Sails autoloads and globalizes them. You wouldn't have it in plain Node.